# Reference error while trying make call to different end points

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to call a odata end Point and check the response and make a another call to different endpoint if the condition is not met. If I don’t have the condition and making just one call to just one end point it works, but below code is throwing Reference error even with the attempt to the first call

```
    $scope.getRequest = function () {
        var url = $rootScope.BaseURL;
        var config = {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Basic ${$scope.key}`,
                'Prefer': 'odata.maxpagesize=2000'
            }
        };
        $http.get(url, config)
            .then(
            function (response) { // success async
                $scope.viewRequest.data = response.data;
            },
            function (response) { // failure async
                console.log("There was an error getting the request from CORE");
            }
        );

        if (viewRequest.data.REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST.length = 0) {
            var url = $rootScope.BaseURL + `CMQ_REQUEST('${$scope.viewRequest.barcode}’)`;
            var config = {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Basic ${$scope.key}`,
                    'Prefer': 'odata.maxpagesize=2000'
                }
            };
            $http.get(url, config)
                .then(
                function (response1) { // success async
                    $scope.viewRequest1.data = response1.data;
                },
                function (response1) { // failure async
                    console.log("There was an error getting the request from CORE");
                }
                );
        }
    };
```

Below is the screenshot of the error

[image]

```
    $scope.getRequest = function () {
        var url = $rootScope.BaseURL;
        var config = {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Basic ${$scope.key}`,
                'Prefer': 'odata.maxpagesize=2000'
            }
        };
        $http.get(url, config)
            .then(function (response) { // success async
                $scope.viewRequest.data = response.data;
            },
            function (response) { // failure async
                console.log("There was an error getting the request from CORE");
            }
        )
            .then(nextViewRequest);
  };

    var newViewRequest = function (response) {
        var url1 = $rootScope.BaseURL + `CMQ_REQUEST('${$scope.viewRequest.barcode}')`;

        if ($scope.viewRequest.data.REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST.length = 0) {

            return $http.get(url1, config)
                .then(
                function (response1) { // success async
                    $scope.viewRequest1.data = response1.data;
                },
                function (response1) { // failure async
                    console.log("There was an error getting the request from CORE");
                }
                );
        }
        return $q.reject({ message: 'Validations didnt work' });
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making 2 request in parallel rather than wait for the first one to finish and then make the second one, also the code is hard to read. My guess is that the second response is not returning anything because the first condition is not met.

I recommend you to read about [promises chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining) and the [$q service to make custom rejections or resolve promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#reject) in your scenarios to order this logic your code should like something like this:

```
$scope.getRequest = function () {
  // setup url and config
  $http.get(url, config)
  .then(nextViewRequest) // the return of this function will override the next result of the next promise chaining
  .then(function(response) {
    $scope.viewRequest1.data = response.data;
  });
};

var nextViewRequest= function(response) {
  // validations necessary
  if(valid) {
    return  $http.get(url, config);
  } 
  // If conditions are not met, then you can use the $q service to create a rejection
  return $q.reject({message: 'validations on second request failed'});
};
```

Comment: The validation needs to be done on the $scope.viewRequest1.data. can that be accessed in nextViewRequest?

Comment: @user4912134 yes at that moment, the data is the response before you bind it to the `$scope`.
The important part here is that you understand how Chaining works, let's call them requestA, and requestB, both are function that make an `$http` request and both function return: `$http.get...`  when you do: 
`requestA
.then(requestB)
.then(FunctionC)`
In requestB, the first param will be `responseA` , and in the `FunctionC` your first param will be `responseB`

Comment: I tried the chaining but looks like I am missing something please check my recent code.

Comment: @user4912134 Check this code example, but again you need to understand the Promises chaining to solve it:
https://plnkr.co/edit/cxNdSsryptkbbagznHiZ?p=catalogue

Comment: I keep getting response1.data is undefined. Looks like the response from newViewRequest is not received

Comment: I did follow the Plunker. Just not sure how the response from newViewRequest is received in the $scope.viewRequest1.data because I get response1.data is undefined after the call to newViewRequest is made